# Different index set for sequences in $\ell^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following question. Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. We are familiar with $\ell^p$ being a complete space, here the sequences are indexed by the positive integers. What happens if instead, we index by a set that is say uncountable? Could we still prove that this space is complete? I think the answers are yes, but if you were to mirror the proof of showing that $\ell^p$, I do not think the proof would be so rigorous. Could anyone give me any hints/help to get started?

Krull.

Comment: Of course, for example $\mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R}$ is the space of all real-indexed sequences that are bounded equipped with the norm $\|(x_t) - (y_t)\| = \sup_{t} |x_t - y_t|.$ (This is usually known as the space of bounded functions.)

Comment: @WillM. Of course, thank you for the example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1 \leq p <\infty$ For any non-empty set $I$ we define $\ell^{p}$ as the set of all real (or complex) functions $x$ on $I$ such that $sup_F \sum_{i \in F} |x(i)| <\infty$ where the supremum is taken over all finite subsets $F$ of $I$.  If $x \in \ell^{p}$ then $x(i)=0$ for al but countably many values of $i$. So if you start with a Cauchy sequence $(x^{n})$ in $\ell^{p}$  the there exists one countable set $I_0$ such that $x^{n}_i=0$ for all $n$ whenever $i \notin I_0$. Now the proof of convergence of this Cauchy sequence reduces to the proof for ordinary $\ell^{p}$.

If $p=\infty$ then we are considering all bounded functions on $I$ with the supremum norm. If $(f_n)$ is Cauchy then $(f_n(i))$ is Cauchy for each $i$ so $f(i)=\lim f_n(i)$ exists. Now if we have $\sup_i|f_n(i)-f_m(i)|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq n_0$ we get $\sup_i|f_n(i)-f(i)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$  which proves completeness.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Does this still work when $p$ is infinite?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull I have edited.